# How to passthrough an usb hub to a vm (based on kvm)?

Tags: usb, qemu, kvm, libvirt, pass-through

linux kernel 4.9.7

libvirt 2.4.0

qemu 2.7.0

HOST:

i7 6700

ASUS B250M-PLUS

2xGTX1060 3GB

500Wpower

1x PCIEtoUSB3.0 card (Reneses chip)

I have two VMs using different GPU

I'm using usb controller passthrough now

VM1 has motherboard controller

VM2 has the PCIE CARD

BUT!!!!!!it is instability!!!!!

mouse and keyboard will be no use sometimes

so i am thinking about passthrough usb hub to be stable

is there any way to do it

Answer (score 0):

this question is interesting. But you should provide more infos about the problem, how you started the machine, what precisel is working and what not.
Btw, use some more time to format your question...

Maybe you background is, that it is dificult and mayby impossible to passthrough an hub to a vom using the normal QEMU VID/PID combination. You can probably show the VM the hub, but all devcices connected to it are still owned by the host.^^

The only way I see is to pass through your nice PCIe USB3.0 controller to your desired VM. You need to enable the IOMMU feature in Grub for KVM to do so. But then it will work.